# Datatable destroy function not working as expected

Tags: datatable, destroy

I'm trying to implement a web app, with a Basic and an Advanced Search, and I'm using datatable 1.10 and jquery 2.2 to display the results of the searches. I'm having issues with the destroy method and I hope that some of you it is going to be able to help me find a solution, thanks in advance to all for your help

Let me explain a little bit my project, code logic, objective and issue:

I have one single table with 5 columns as you can see on my jsfiddle. I also have a global variable "table" to handle the datatable (DT) once it is created. I declared a function "loadSearchData" to load the parameters for the Ajax call on another global variable. On the click event of my two Search buttons I check if the DT already exists then I destroy it, and then I call the function "initializeDataTable". My idea was to destroy the existing DT and create a new one each time the Search buttons are clicked. However it is not working, and the behavior is "weird":

First time I enter the search criteria and click search, works perfectly fine If I modifiy the search criteria and click search again, then I get a Webpage error

"Line: 1 Error: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference"

Then, if don't debug and click the search button again, then it works perfectly fine again!

The code:

```
            //BASIC SEARCH
            $('#btnBasicSearch').on('click', function () {

                $("#partialSearch").removeAttr("hidden");

                loadSearchData('basicSearch');

                if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tbDocumentsList'))  {
                    table.destroy();                    
                }

                initializeDataTable(searchParameters);
            });

            //ADVANCED SEARCH
            $("#btnSearch").on('click', function () {

                $("#partialSearch").removeAttr("hidden");
                loadSearchData('advancedSearch');
                jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

                if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tbDocumentsList')) {
                    table.destroy();                    
                }

                initializeDataTable(searchParameters);

            });
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, this is my first time using datatables and probably I'm missing something, anyone have any idea?

You can see the complete jsfiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/dalps/gxgLdo03/

I also asked on the datatable forum:

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33563/datatable-destroy-function-not-working-as-expected#latest

thanks in advance

dalps

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got my answer on the datatable forum: my html table have 5 columns and on the "columndefs" property I have the following:

"targets": 5, 
"data": "active", 
"visible": false

since the column indexing begin with zero, I was referencing a column that doesn't exist, solution, add a new column to the table